# How to join RSS feeds into one? (from php)

Tags: php, join, rss, feed

How to join RSS feeds into one? (from php) what libs can help us with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [SimpleXML](http://uk.php.net/simplexml)

Either that, or you can use something like Yahoo! Pipes to merge them for you can create a merged RSS feed for you.

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/

if you use pipes, be sure to filter by date, so you can get a feed with all the posts in chronological order. I've used it for a few things and it works great!

Comment: pipes is no more, unfortunately https://web.archive.org/web/20150604181928/http://pipes.yqlblog.net/post/120705592639/pipes-end-of-life-announcement